# Не получается установить пакеты в PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, pip

При попытке установки пакетов выдает ошибку.
Например:
При попытке установить пакет pycrypto. Получаю ошибку:

```
Collecting pycrypto   Using cached pycrypto-2.6.1.tar.gz (446 kB) Building wheels for collected packages: pycrypto   Building wheel for pycrypto (setup.py): started   Building wheel for pycrypto (setup.py): finished with status 'error'   Running setup.py clean for pycrypto Failed to build pycrypto Installing collected packages: pycrypto
    Running setup.py install for pycrypto: started
    Running setup.py install for pycrypto: finished with status 'error'

  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:    command: 'C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\evgpe\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\pycrypto\\setup.py'"'"';
__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\evgpe\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\pycrypto\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\evgpe\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-uxwv31iu'
       cwd: C:\Users\evgpe\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pycrypto\   Complete output (153 lines):   running bdist_wheel   running build   running build_py   creating build   creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8   creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto   copying lib\Crypto\pct_warnings.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto   copying lib\Crypto\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto   creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Hash   copying lib\Crypto\Hash\hashalgo.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Hash   copying lib\Crypto\Hash\HMAC.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Hash copying lib\Crypto\Hash\MD2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Hash  copying lib\Crypto\Hash\MD4.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Hash  copying lib\Crypto\Hash\MD5.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Hash  copying lib\Crypto\Hash\RIPEMD.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Hash   copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA.py
-> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Hash   copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA224.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Hash   copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA256.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Hash   copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA384.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Hash   copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA512.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Hash   copying lib\Crypto\Hash\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Hash   creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Cipher   copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\AES.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Cipher   copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\ARC2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Cipher   copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\ARC4.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Cipher   copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\blockalgo.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Cipher   copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\Blowfish.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Cipher copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\CAST.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Cipher   copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\DES.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Cipher   copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\DES3.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Cipher   copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\PKCS1_OAEP.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Cipher   copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\PKCS1_v1_5.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Cipher   copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\XOR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Cipher   copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Cipher   creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Util   copying lib\Crypto\Util\asn1.py
-> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Util   copying lib\Crypto\Util\Counter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Util   copying lib\Crypto\Util\number.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Util   copying lib\Crypto\Util\py3compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Util   copying lib\Crypto\Util\randpool.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Util   copying lib\Crypto\Util\RFC1751.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Util   copying lib\Crypto\Util\winrandom.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Util   copying lib\Crypto\Util\_number_new.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Util  copying lib\Crypto\Util\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Util   creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Random   copying lib\Crypto\Random\random.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Random   copying lib\Crypto\Random\_UserFriendlyRNG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Random   copying lib\Crypto\Random\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Random creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Random\Fortuna   copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\FortunaAccumulator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Random\Fortuna   copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\FortunaGenerator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Random\Fortuna   copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\SHAd256.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Random\Fortuna   copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Random\Fortuna   creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Random\OSRNG   copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\fallback.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Random\OSRNG   copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\nt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Random\OSRNG   copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\posix.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Random\OSRNG   copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\rng_base.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Random\OSRNG   copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Random\OSRNG   creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest   copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\st_common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest   copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest   creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher   copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher   copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_AES.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher   copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_ARC2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher   copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_ARC4.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher   copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_Blowfish.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher   copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_CAST.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher   copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_DES.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher   copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_DES3.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher   copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_pkcs1_15.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher   copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_pkcs1_oaep.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher   copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_XOR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher   copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher   creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash   copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash   copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_HMAC.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash   copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_MD2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash   copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_MD4.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash   copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_MD5.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash   copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_RIPEMD.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash   copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash   copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA224.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash   copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA256.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash   copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA384.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash   copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA512.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash   copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash   creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol   copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_AllOrNothing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol   copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_chaffing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol   copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_KDF.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol   copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_rfc1751.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol   copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol   creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey   copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_DSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey   copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_ElGamal.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey   copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_importKey.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey   copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_RSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey   copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey   creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random   copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\test_random.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random   copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\test_rpoolcompat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random   copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\test__UserFriendlyRNG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random   copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random   creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna   copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\test_FortunaAccumulator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna   copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\test_FortunaGenerator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna   copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\test_SHAd256.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna   copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna   creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG   copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_fallback.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG   copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_generic.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG   copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_nt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG   copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_posix.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG   copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_winrandom.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG   copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG   creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Util   copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_asn1.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Util   copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_Counter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Util   copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_number.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Util   copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_winrandom.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Util   copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Util   creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature   copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_pkcs1_15.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature   copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_pkcs1_pss.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature   copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature   creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Protocol   copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\AllOrNothing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Protocol   copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\Chaffing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Protocol   copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\KDF.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Protocol  copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Protocol   creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\PublicKey   copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\DSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\PublicKey   copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\ElGamal.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\PublicKey   copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\pubkey.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\PublicKey   copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\RSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\PublicKey   copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\_DSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\PublicKey   copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\_RSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\PublicKey   copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\_slowmath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\PublicKey   copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\PublicKey   creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Signature   copying lib\Crypto\Signature\PKCS1_PSS.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Signature   copying lib\Crypto\Signature\PKCS1_v1_5.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Signature   copying lib\Crypto\Signature\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Signature   Skipping optional fixer: buffer   Skipping optional fixer: idioms   Skipping optional fixer: set_literal   Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma   running build_ext   warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.   building 'Crypto.Random.OSRNG.winrandom' extension   error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/  
----------------------------------------   ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycrypto
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\evgpe\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\pycrypto\\setup.py'"'"';
__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\evgpe\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\pycrypto\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\evgpe\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-3k3knkdk\install-record.txt'
--single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Program Files\Python38\Include\pycrypto'
         cwd: C:\Users\evgpe\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pycrypto\
    Complete output (153 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto
    copying lib\Crypto\pct_warnings.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto
    copying lib\Crypto\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\hashalgo.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\HMAC.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\MD2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\MD4.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\MD5.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\RIPEMD.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA224.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA256.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA384.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA512.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Hash
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\AES.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\ARC2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\ARC4.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\blockalgo.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\Blowfish.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\CAST.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\DES.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\DES3.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\PKCS1_OAEP.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\PKCS1_v1_5.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\XOR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Cipher
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\asn1.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\Counter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\number.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\py3compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\randpool.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\RFC1751.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\winrandom.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\_number_new.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Util
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\random.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\_UserFriendlyRNG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Random
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\FortunaAccumulator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\FortunaGenerator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\SHAd256.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\fallback.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\nt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\posix.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\rng_base.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\st_common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_AES.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_ARC2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_ARC4.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_Blowfish.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_CAST.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_DES.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_DES3.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_pkcs1_15.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_pkcs1_oaep.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_XOR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_HMAC.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_MD2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_MD4.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_MD5.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_RIPEMD.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA224.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA256.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA384.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA512.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_AllOrNothing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_chaffing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_KDF.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_rfc1751.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_DSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_ElGamal.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_importKey.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_RSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\test_random.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\test_rpoolcompat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\test__UserFriendlyRNG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\test_FortunaAccumulator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\test_FortunaGenerator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\test_SHAd256.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_fallback.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_generic.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_nt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_posix.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_winrandom.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_asn1.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_Counter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_number.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_winrandom.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_pkcs1_15.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_pkcs1_pss.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\AllOrNothing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\Chaffing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\KDF.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Protocol
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\DSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\ElGamal.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\pubkey.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\RSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\_DSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\_RSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\_slowmath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\PublicKey
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\Signature\PKCS1_PSS.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\Signature\PKCS1_v1_5.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\Signature\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Crypto\Signature
    Skipping optional fixer: buffer
    Skipping optional fixer: idioms
    Skipping optional fixer: set_literal
    Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
    running build_ext
    warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.
    building 'Crypto.Random.OSRNG.winrandom' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ---------------------------------------- ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\evgpe\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\pycrypto\\setup.py'"'"';
__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\evgpe\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\pycrypto\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\evgpe\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-3k3knkdk\install-record.txt'
--single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Program Files\Python38\Include\pycrypto' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Описываю танцы с бубном что уже проделал.
1. Переустановил Python. Проверил через командную строку. Все поставилось норм.
2. Переустановил PyCharm.
3. Обновил Microsoft Visual C++.

Хз в чем дело....

Comment: На какой интерпретатор черз командную строку библиотека поставилась?

Comment: Вбивал такую команду:
C:\Program Files\Python38> pip install pycrypto 
(версия Python 3.8.2 64)

Comment: А что `where pip` возвращает?

Comment: Решил свою проблему установкой библиотеки напрямую в каталог Lib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил вопрос копированием папки simple-crypt напрямую в папку Lib в Папке Python'а. Всем спасибо за помощь.